# JTextArea font change is slow

Tags: java, jtextarea

I have a curious problem with the JTextArea control:

When I bring up my `JTextArea` everything is fine and whatever I type shows up without delay. However as soon as I send a `FontSizeAction` to my `EditorKit` (RTFEditorKit in this case, but it does not seem to matter which I use), a delay, from 1 - several seconds, happens.

Interestingly the delay only happens after you type something, that is a font change followed by doing nothing and then typing, makes no difference from just typing immediately. The delay is the same. I can see that right after typing the first letter after a FontSizeAction, allocation increases with a couple of megs.

I have used a profiler on the application and there's nothing in my own app that seems to be the problem.

**My code:**

```
private void updateFont(MainModelManager model) {
    (new RTFEditorKit.FontSizeAction("font-size-" + model.getFontSize(),
                                     model.getFontSize())).actionPerformed(
        new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, null) );

    (new RTFEditorKit.FontFamilyAction("font-family-" + model.getFontFamily(), model.getFontFamily())).actionPerformed(
            new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, model.getFontFamily()) );
}
```

This is part of the declaration of the main model container:

```
public class MainModelManager extends Observable {
    DefaultStyledDocument doc;
    int fontSize = 12;
    String fontType = "Helvetica";
    StyleContext sc; 
    Caret editorCaret;
    boolean editorFrameIsResizable;  
    //...
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I think I have narrowed to problem down to the FontFamilyAction because, if I comment it out the delay disappears and I can still change the font size without a problem. Maybe this has something to do with loading fonts?

Comment: can you post some relevant code?

Comment: Can you profile everything, including JDK classes?

Comment: Are you accessing the Swing component outside of the Swing worker thread? I've seen this of type of weird behavior when altering Swing components from a different thread.

Comment: I can only profile my own classes. My general structure is MVC application so I only access the swing components from inside the JFrame where the JTextarea is nested in, and as I have not forked any threads off I guess it is only accessed from the worker thread. 

Concerning code, I am in a bit of doubt about what to post as I have no idea where the problem stems from. I'll try to add some code though.